# Invalid data source name

Tags: php

Trying to get a website blog working and getting invalid data source name error.

Tried making some changes to the code and corrected some previous errors.

db_connection.php

```
<?php
function OpenCon()
 {
 $dbhost = "localhost";
 $dbuser = "root";
 $dbpass = "﻿123";
 $db = "db";
 $conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass,$db) or die("Connect 
failed: 
%s\n". $conn -> error);

 return $conn;
 }

function CloseCon($conn)
 {
 $conn -> close();
 }﻿

?>﻿﻿﻿
```

index.php

```
try {
        ﻿   

            // $stmt = db->query('SELECT postID, postTitle, postDesc, postDate FROM blog_posts ORDER BY postID DESC');
            $conn = new PDO('SELECT postID, postTitle, postDesc, postDate FROM blog_posts ORDER BY postID DESC');
            while($﻿row = $stmt->fetch()){

                echo '<div>';
                    echo '<h1><a href="viewpost.php?id='.$row['postID'].'">'.$row['postTitle'].'</a></h1>';
                    ﻿echo '<p>Posted on '.date('jS M Y H:i:s', strtotime($row['postDate'])).'</p>';
                    echo '<p>'.$row['postDesc'].'</p>';             
                    echo '<p><a href="viewpost.php?id='.$row['postID'].'">Read More</a></p>';               
                echo '</div>';

            }
```

The expected results should be a website blog page
The actual results are page saying invalid data source name.

Comment: You use both PDO and mysqli in your app, pick one and use it.

Comment: Also you open a PDO connection by provide login information, currently you are providing a SQL command. Read how to use PDO here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php

Comment: Thank you for your help, so I think I will try PDO but do I need to modify both of my files? index.php and db_connection.php? I read the manual but still unsure...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to be using PDO here is some sample code that will get you going in the right direction.

db_connection.php

```
<?php
$host = 'localhost'; $db = 'db_name'; $user = 'user'; $pw = 'password';
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$db.';charset=utf8', $user, $pw);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
?>
```

index.php

above the `<head>`

```
<?php
require("path/to/file/1_ErrorReporting.php"); // this is the file that will allow you to see errors during production
// don't forget to remove the line or remark it out with double forward slashes when going live
require('path/to/folder/db_connection.php');

$sql = "SELECT `postID`, `postTitle`, `postDesc`, `postDate` FROM `blog_posts` ORDER BY `postID` DESC";
$query = $conn->prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
$results = $query->fetchAll();
$totalRows = $query->rowCount();
?>
```

Notice the "back-ticks" surrounding the table name and column names. This is always a good idea just in case you happen to use a reserved word for a table or column name.

1_ErrorReporting.php

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>
```

In the body of your index.php page

```
<?php
foreach($results as $row) {
    echo '<div>'.
    '<h1><a href="viewpost.php?id='.$row['postID'].'">'.$row['postTitle'].'</a></h1>'.
   '<p>Posted on '.date('jS M Y H:i:s', strtotime($row['postDate'])).'</p>'.
   '<p>'.$row['postDesc'].'</p>'.
   '<p><a href="viewpost.php?id='.$row['postID'].'">Read More</a></p>'.
   '</div>';
}
?>
```

No need to write echo on every line. Simply end the line with a period until the last line you want to echo, then end with a semi-colon.

At the bottom of your index.php page

```
</body>
</html>
<?php
$query->closeCursor();
$conn = null;
?>
```

Comment: I made the changes you said and I get a webpage that shows, foreach($results as $row) { echo '
'. '
'.$row['postTitle'].'
'. '
Posted on '.date('jS M Y H:i:s', strtotime($row['postDate'])).'
'. '
'.$row['postDesc'].'
'. '
Read More
'. '
'; }

Answer (score 0):

You are not executing your select statement. You can try this

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=YOURSERVERNAME;dbname=YOUR DB NAME", YOUR USERNAME, YOUR PASSWORD);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT postID, postTitle, postDesc, postDate FROM blog_posts ORDER BY postID DESC"); 
$stmt->execute();

while($﻿row = $stmt->fetch()){
   echo '<div>';
       echo '<h1><a href="viewpost.php?id='.$row['postID'].'">'.$row['postTitle'].'</a></h1>';
       ﻿echo '<p>Posted on '.date('jS M Y H:i:s', strtotime($row['postDate'])).'</p>';
       echo '<p>'.$row['postDesc'].'</p>';             
       echo '<p><a href="viewpost.php?id='.$row['postID'].'">Read More</a></p>';               
   echo '</div>';
```

Comment: which file would i include that code in, and thank you everyone for helping me so far.

Comment: i missed a php tag that you had, i put it in and it works thank you all for your help!!!